# Im having trouble with nested attributes in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am trying to make a forum like feature on my website, but I am running into an issue with nested attributes. I have a Topic model that holds a title and I have a Post model that holds content. The code in my topic model holds

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :forum
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts

end
```

and in my view I im trying to access the content variable like this

```
<% if @topic.errors.any? %>
<div class="alert alert-danger"> 
<p>The form contains <%= pluralize(@topic.errors.count, "error") %>.</p>
</div>
<ul>
  <% @topic.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
  <li class="text-danger"> <%= message %> </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>

<div class='form-group'>
  <%= f.label :title, "Title*" %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>

<%= f.fields_for :posts do |ff| %>
 <div class='form-group'>
    <%= ff.label :content, "Content*" %>
    <%= ff.text_area :content, size: "25x6", class: 'form-control' %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

This is just a partial and which is run in my new.html.erb but when I run it it only shows my title text field and not the content text area? Anyone have any ideas and if they have any more questions because I didn't explain it well, feel free to ask.

Edit:

Here is my topic controller.

```
class TopicsController < ApplicationController

 def index
 end

 def new
  forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
  @topic = forum.topics.build
  post = @topic.posts.build
 end

def create
  forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
  @topic = forum.topics.build(topic_params)
  post = @topic.posts.build
  if @topic.save and post.save then
    flash[:success] = "Topic Posted"
    redirect_to @topic
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def show
end

def edit
end

def update
end

def destroy
  forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
  if current_user.admin? then
    @topic.destroy
    flash[:success] = @topic.title + " destroyed!"
    redirect_to forum_topic_path(forum)
  else
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end

private

def topic_params
  params.require(:topic).permit(:title, :content)
end

end
```

Comment: Have you defined a foreign key topic_id in your Post model?

Comment: I added a topic_id in the migration but is it suppose to be an index or is it called something special? Right now it just t.integer topic_id.

Comment: Please check to make sure that you've built `posts` in your `new` action. i.e. `@topic.posts.build` after `@topic = Topic.new`.

Comment: Well I can't do Topic.new because I have to link it up with the forum if I was told correctly. So in my 1`new` action i just did `@topic = forum.topics.build` then `post = @topic.posts.build`

Comment: Right now when I try to create a new topic in my new view. When I type stuff in the title and the content and press submit it says that content doesn't have anything in it but it does of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might not fix your problem, but you have some syntax which needs fixing:

```
def create
 topic = Topic.new(topic_params)
  if topic.save then
    flash[:success] = "Topic Posted"
    redirect_to @topic
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def topic_params
    params.require(:topic).permit(:title, post_attributes: [:content]).merge(:forum_id => params[:forum_id])
end
```

Your `topics` table should have the foreign_keys `user_id` & `forum_id` with `title`. Your `posts` table should have the foreign key `topic_id`

This *should* work from looking at your code. If not, it will be helpful to see your console errors for the call

Comment: So this doesn't error out when I click the submit button but it still doesn't show the content on the next page that the user just posted. Any ideas?

Comment: You'll probably have an unpermitted params problem -- any way you could show the log for the request; specifically the POST request?

Comment: Sorry didn't realize comments had limits, So I tried to add the POST log info but had trouble formatting. So it said that there is an `Unpermitted parameters: posts_attributes` when I tried passing through `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"1DkrAoa9npbnNh/dp+puLFTm055RkD4O9mrBE71RkYU=", "topic"=>{"title"=>"So what about this?", "posts_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"content"=>"adasdasdas"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Topic", "forum_id"=>"2"}
Unpermitted parameters: posts_attributes`.

Comment: Oh and by the way my topics table has a user_id and forum_id and post has a user_id and a topic_id.

Comment: Okay, the good news is Rails recognizes the nested attribute (it wouldn't create `posts_attributes` otherwise). From your error, the first port-of-call is to permit "posts_attributes" in the strong params, here:
`params.require(:topic).permit(:title, posts_attributes: [:content]).merge(:forum_id => params[:forum_id], :user_id => current_user.id)`